# "Symbols for image file Entities.dll could not be found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am having the following problem.

Data:

1. I have a TFS Build Controller+Agent machine. I have there VS2013 Update 5 Installed.
2. I am running a build step which executes the following code:

   ```
   using (var coverageInfo =     CoverageInfo.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(cmdArgs.CoverageFile), executableDirectories, executableDirectories))
   {
       using (var coverageDs = coverageInfo.BuildDataSet())
       {
         coverageDs.WriteXml(cmdArgs.OutputFile);
       }
     }
   ```

When that steps is executed in the Build Server there is an exception:

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.SymbolsNotFoundException: Symbols for image file "Entities.dll" could not be found.

The thing is that, when I run that same code from my local machine, pointing to the same folders as the build machine, everything runs fine.

Any idea of what I can check?

Regards!

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or vNext build? Here is a VS2012 flag in your post, where do you install it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by installing VS 2012. Let me explain. The image below shows the project that was giving problems. As you can see, there are two references to *.Analysis and *.Symbols. These two dlls are referenced by PATH:

C:\Projects\Build\Dev\ActivityPack\References\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll
C:\Projects\Build\Dev\ActivityPack\References\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Symbols.dll

[image]

The thing is that it looks like those DLLs need additional components installed by VS 2010.

I was getting this error:

```
Faulting application name: secondaryinstaller.exe, version: 14.0.23107.0, time stamp: 0x559b70e4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.17366, time stamp: 0x554d16f6
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00010192
Faulting process id: 0xac0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d12714fefee4bd
Faulting application path: D:\d6da799e8cfbca473168b6f82eb35b\secondaryinstaller.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dd1fc757-9308-11e5-9431-005056b4190f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

As you can see, the error is thrown by the Kernel, which makes me thing, in my ignorance, that there got to be a COM somewhere that is being referenced.

Thank you @cece for caring!